# Process terminated with status -1073741510 - C++ Prime Factorization

Tags: c++, return, return-type, function-definition

I am writing a code for Prime factorization of a number but I am not able to run my program, encountering the *Process terminated with status -1073741510* I am new to computer science. Please find my code below:

PrimeFactorize function

```
int primeFactorize(int n) {
  if (isPrime(n)) {
    cout<<n;
  }

  for(int i = 2; i < sqrt(n); i++) {
    if(!isPrime(i))
        continue;
    while(n % i == 0) {
        cout<<i;
        n /= i;
    }
  }
}
```

isPrimeMethod

```
bool isPrime(int n) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    return false;
  }
  for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0)
        return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Main Method

```
int main() {
  cout<<primeFactorize(100);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your function `int primeFactorize(int n)` doesn't `return` anything, despite declaring it so and even trying to use the return value.

Comment: When you get a weird number like  -1073741510, convert it to hex (C000013A) and see if it is more recognizable.

Comment: Did you get any warnings from the compiler?

Comment: It is not  what causes the termination, but note that here call to `isPrime` is useless and slow down your programme

Answer (score 2):

Your function

```
int primeFactorize(int n);
```

returns nothing. Therefore this statement

```
cout<<primeFactorize(100);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You should change the function declaration the following way

```
std::vector<int> primeFactorize(int n);
```

And within the function instead of outputting prime divisors you should pass them in the vector. For example

```
  for(int i = 2; i < sqrt(n); i++) {
    if( isPrime(i)) {
        while(n % i == 0) {
            v.push_back( i );
            n /= i;
        }
    }
  }
```

And the function must return the vector.

In main you can output the obtained vector.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, specifically the function: `int primeFactorize(int n)` returns *nothing* inside the body. Which invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

It will *need* to return an `int` value of some-sort. Functions that return a *value* are called *value-returning functions*.

When using *data types*, like `int`, `double`, `bool` they all need to end up *returning* their respective data types back to the statement that called the function.

For your code specifically, it should not even have a value-returning function. Instead, it should just use `void`. `void` simple enough, does not *return* a value.

Changing this piece:

`int primeFactorize(int n)`

to:

`void primeFactorize(int n)`

Should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused between functions which return something (e.g. `isPrime`) and functions which print something but return nothing (e.g. `primeFactorize`). Printing is not the same as returning. You can tell `primeFactorize` doesn't return anything because there is no `return ...;` statement in it.

Functions which don't return anything should be declared `void` like this

```
void primeFactorize(int n)
{
    ...
}
```

and then you should change `main` so that you don't try to print the return value of `primeFactorize` (which no longer exists).

```
int main()
{
    primeFactorize(100);
    return 0;
}
```